# Multiple FOR loops in iterating over dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

This is a simplistic example of a dictionary created by a json.load that I have t deal with:

```
{
    "name": "USGS REST Services Query",
    "queryInfo": {
        "timePeriod": "PT4H",
        "format": "json",
        "data": {
            "sites": [{
                "id": "03198000",
                "params": "[00060, 00065]"
            },
            {
                "id": "03195000",
                "params": "[00060, 00065]"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes there may be 15-100 sites with unknown sets of parameters at each site.  My goal is to either create two lists (one storing "site" IDs and the other storing "params") or a much simplified dictionary from this original dictionary.  Is there a way to do this using nested for loops with kay,value pairs using the iteritem() method?

What I have tried to far is this:

```
queryDict = {}

for key,value in WS_Req_dict.iteritems():
    if key == "queryInfo":
        if value == "data":
            for key, value in WS_Req_dict[key][value].iteritems():
                if key == "sites":
                    siteVal = key
                    if value == "params":
                        paramList = [value]
                        queryDict["sites"] = siteVal
                        queryDict["sites"]["params"] = paramList
```

I run into trouble getting the second FOR loop to work.  I haven't looked into pulling out lists yet.

I think this maybe an overall stupid way of doing it, but I can't see around it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make your code much simpler by just indexing, when feasible, rather than looping over `iteritems`.

```
for site in WS_Req_dict['queryInfo']['data']['sites']:
    queryDict[site['id']] = site['params']
```

If some of the keys might be missing, `dict`'s `get` method is your friend:

```
for site in WS_Req_dict.get('queryInfo',{}).get('data',{}).get('sites',[]):
```

would let you quietly ignore missing keys.  But, this is much less readable, so, if I needed it, I'd encapsulate it into a function -- and often you may not need this level of precaution!   (Another good alternative is a `try/except KeyError` encapsulation to ignore missing keys, if they are indeed possible in your specific use case).

Comment: Two things - are you missing a bracket somewhere?  and what does queryID do?  Is queryID a new dictionary you are suggesting to use there?

Comment: I think the brackets are OK, but `queryId` is just how I spelled the resulting `dict` -- editing to use `queryDict` as you had originally, no real reason to change its name.

Comment: Can you help me clear up this error real quick:  "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: No I can't -- in your example data, none of the things being indexed would be a string.  Break it down so you know **which** indexing is failing -- what is a string that's supposed to be a dictionary.  Append the decomposed code and error traceback to your Q if you can't tell.  I'm off to bed so I won't be able to help until tomorrow morning, but likely somebody else will.

Comment: I got it.  Got rid of one of the sites to simplify, but that f'ed it up.  all good now.